# How to convert currency to a number?

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

i am loading a file which has an amount column and it contains values like 123,56€ 
when i loaded into hive table , the euro symbol gets replaced by a square box,
and the second thing is that the comma indicates a decimal.

Now  i want a regex which can convert this value into 123.56 so basically remove  comma and euro symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
regexp_extract(regexp_replace('123,56€',',','.' ),'([0-9.]+)', 1)
```

This will give 123.56

Comment: thanks for the reply.but the value is 123,56€ and not 123,56 something like regexp_replace(regexp_replace('123,56€','€','' ),',','.'); but i dont want to go by this approach , i want to extarct only numbers, that is replace , with . and then extract number only

Comment: can u explain the regexp_extract pls?

Comment: ([0-9.]+) ... you need only number and . in the output hence it will filter the characters specified in between.

Answer (score 1):

```
hive> select translate('123,56€',',€','.');
OK
123.56
```

And if you have unknown currency symbols

```
hive> select translate('123,56€',translate('123,56€','1234567890',''),'.');
OK
123.56
```

Answer (score 0):

```
hive> select regexp_replace('123,56€','(\\d+),(\\d+).','$1.$2');
OK
123.56
```

and you probably want it as a number

```
hive> select cast(regexp_replace('123,56€','(\\d+),(\\d+).','$1.$2') as decimal(12,2));
OK
123.56
```

Comment: I think there might be even a cleaner solution without regex. I'll check later